# Python Scripting: (relative) Locations and Rotations of Objects under Empty

Tags: python, scripting

The title says it all..

I'm looking for an easy way to get a list of the relative locations and rotation (Euler) and Mesh names of all Objects (meshes) under each Empty in my project.. But I'm not good with Python, let alone with loops inside Python.

Anyone willing to help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Search for answers, use the python console**

The piece of advice I'd impart for those keen on learning python via blender, is to get your hands dirty and *"nut these things out"* yourself

Here is python console code. Firstly get all the empties in the scene objects collection via a list comprehension.  `C` is context.

```
>>> empties = [e for e in C.scene.objects if e.data is None]
```

Then loop thru the child objects of each of empties.  Writes the object's name, its location and euler rotation from the basis matrix and directly from the properties.

For global use `ob.matrix_world`

```
>>> for e in empties:
...     for o in e.children:
...         o.name
...         o.matrix_basis.to_translation()
...         o.location
...         o.matrix_basis.to_euler()
...         o.rotation_euler
...
```

Output

```
'Icosphere'
Vector((0.08762237429618835, -0.26966890692710876, -0.9004361629486084))
Vector((0.08762237429618835, -0.26966890692710876, -0.9004361629486084))
Euler((2.8039052486419678, 7.291294679134808e-08, 0.31416523456573486), 'XYZ')
Euler((2.8039052486419678, 7.291294679134808e-08, 0.31416523456573486), 'XYZ')
'Icosphere.001'
Vector((0.47059956192970276, -0.5479161143302917, -0.6078704595565796))
Vector((0.47059956192970276, -0.5479161143302917, -0.6078704595565796))
Euler((2.2938785552978516, -1.0633498526146923e-08, 0.679742157459259), 'XYZ')
Euler((2.2938785552978516, -1.0633498526146923e-08, 0.679742157459259), 'XYZ')
'Icosphere.002'
Vector((-0.05865825340151787, -0.7198853492736816, -0.6078706383705139))
Vector((-0.05865825340151787, -0.7198853492736816, -0.6078706383705139))
Euler((2.2938790321350098, -1.5278347476055387e-08, -0.051412295550107956), 'XYZ')
Euler((2.2938790321350098, -1.5278347476055387e-08, -0.051412295550107956), 'XYZ')
```

Comment: That is helping me on my way a lot. Thank you.

Now I'm struggling to find the reference to the Mesh name that is connected to the object. 

o.mesh doesn't exist.. o.id doesn't exit.. any chance you know how to find it?

Answer (score -1):

Great! With the help of batFINGER I made the following solution:

```
import bpy
import os
import bgl, blf, mathutils

C = bpy.context

empties = [e for e in C.scene.objects if e.data is None]

for e in empties:
    for o in e.children:
        o.matrix_basis.to_translation()
        o.matrix_basis.to_euler()
        if o.type=='MESH':
            mystring = str(o.data)
            namestring = mystring[19:len(mystring) - 3]
            mystring = str(o.location)
            locationtring = mystring[8:len(mystring) - 3]
            mystring = str(o.rotation_euler)
            rotationstring = mystring[7:len(mystring) - 14]
            print (namestring, ',', locationtring, ',', rotationstring)
```

This can just be copy-pasted in a script, with the output coming through the System Console. Hope it helps someone :)

Comment: Good point. 
Okay, so the code above can be run straight as a script in Blender. It will return Mesh name, location and rotation of all Meshes that are grouped under an Empty.
This was exactly what I needed :)

Comment: Hmm.. I'm not so sure about that: The example code could help a reader to interpret other readers how to put 'Console Code' provided by batFINGER into a Script that is ready-to-run. But you're right that perhaps I could have been clearer about that.